# Maintaining session in android

Tags: android, asp.net, session

I have seen various answers for the topic and implemented them but nothing worked.I am posting my implementation code here.I need to know why the code isn't working

I have loginhttpPost method which sends username,password to the asp server for authentication and stores the session ID from the response in " cookieId "

cookieId is something like "erzt ..."

```
public String loginhttpPost(String username, String password)
        throws ConnectTimeoutException {
        try {
            // --------post


            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(loginurl);



            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET", ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTARGUMENT", ""));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE",viewstateValue));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION",eventvalidateValue));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cphBody$txtUserName",username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cphBody$txtPassword", password));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$cphBody$btnLogin","Login"));


            httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // perform post

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);


            // get session id and store in cookieId

            cookieId =""; 
            List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
            for (Cookie cookie: cookies){
                if (cookie.getName().equals("ASP.NET_SessionId")){
                    cookieId = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }


            Log.d("COOKIE",cookieId);


            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            Log.d("CHECK", "INSIDE METHOD");

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        }

    return response;
}
```

Now i am using defaultHttpGet method to perform subsequent get requests to the server after authentication by sending the session id with the requests

```
public String defaulthttpGet(String url) throws ConnectTimeoutException{

    try {


        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("Cookie","ASP.NET_SessionId="+cookieId);

        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());


    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    }

     return response;
}
```

But i am getting the login page instead of intended page

NOTE : i am using the same HttpClient for subsequent requests

Comment: Those two functions are ASP.NET code behind functions in a Page? Who is calling `defaulthttpGet`?

Comment: i am using defaulthttpGet for subsequent requests to the server after authenticating with username & password

Comment: Yes. WHERE is it called, and when, and by whom?

Comment: the method is called in doInBackground of AsynTask within a Fragment

Comment: yeah ... loginhttpPost works perfectly from the client side by submitting the login details and accessing the asp page but when i use defaulthttpGet it seems the session is lost eventhough i use static HttpClient

Comment: I still don't see how you call that function from the client. Please post the code.

Comment: replacing httpget.addHeader("Cookie","ASP.NET_SessionId="+cookieId); with httppost.addHeader("Cookie","ASP.NET_SessionId="+cookieId+"; path=/");  solved my problem